# R markdown and MikTex not syncing

Tags: r, compiler-errors, markdown, r-markdown, miktex

I have been using R and Texworks for some time now, but when I try using them together (i.e. R Markdown) things start to go wrong - even at the start. I'm guessing the problem is something really simple, if you know how to fix it please feel free to reply. Here is the chain of events:

1. Installed R and Rstudio and all its necessary packages. R version 3.4.1, Rstudio version 1.0.153 on Windows 10.
2. Installed LyX (2.2) which comes with Texworks and MikTex (2.9) package manager. Installed all necessary packages to get even the most complex dissertations compiling.
3. Open Rstudio.
4. File -> New File -> R Markdown...
5. Select PDF as default output. This then give the introduction template.
6. Click on Knit. ('Answer 'Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your devide?' thrice)
7. Error message in R Markdown window:

   ```
   ! LaTeX Error: File `url.sty' not found.

   Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
   or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

   Enter file name: 
   ! Emergency stop.
   <read *> 

   l.5100 \let

   pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
   In addition: Warning message:
   running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS dfth.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output dfth.pdf --template "C:\Users\ALEX.LAU\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
   Execution halted
   ```

Things I've tried:

1. Installing url.sty in Miktex. Restart Rstudio. Same error.
2. Change output from pdflatex to xelatex (suggestion from a previous post). Get a similar error saying I must install mathspec.sty. Installed mathspec.sty in Miktex. Same error.

Outputting as html works though so I guess there is a problem linking Rstudio/R markdown with Miktex packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Advice, try your .tex file in miktex, using texworks.
By default the tex file is not kept, put an option to keep it

```
---
title: "MyTitle"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```

Compile this in texworks using the typeset arrow, you may have prompts at the bottom asking some questions, type enter if needed. You have a good description of the procedure in [TeXworks-manual](http://formal.korea.ac.kr/~jlee/lectures/cnce150/read/TeXworks-manual.pdf)

If this does not work try out with a very simple example, to try to figure out what's wrong.

> File>new from template>article

This will create a template for article

Add one line `\usepackage{hyperref}`

And test it, you may have to configure things to get the packages downloaded using Miktek setting or options. Once you have solved your problem and can compile a simple tex document, you might be able to run your knitr.